# ASP.NET - WebBrowser - making it wait for a second or two

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, automation, browser

I am using a Webbrowser in ASP.NET to login to a betting site and place a bet.

Once team is found and its click method raised, a side frame/window is loaded by javascript with a textbox to enter the bet ammount.

I've tried :

```
var stakeTextboxElement = doc.GetElementById("stake");
stakeTextboxElement.Focus();
stakeTextboxElement.InnerText = "3";
webbrowser.navigate("javascript: placeBet();"); //they use javascript
```

This gives me an error that my bid is not high enough (when it is). From what i can tell, its navigating too fast and not reading the InnerText as "3";

I've done the exact same scenario in Windows Forms and instead of setting InnerText, i do

```
SendKeys.Send("3"); 
webbrowser.navigate("javascript: placeBet();");
```

Same Error. But this works if i add 'Application.DoEvents();' just before the navigate. Doing the same does not work for the InnerText example.

From what i can tell, i have to tell webbrowser to continue running for a second or two so it reads the textbox with text inside.

Comment: Aside from legal issues with this.. automating a browser is the wrong way to go. You would have more luck actually creating the web requests.

Comment: What legal issues exactly? Why would they care if I had to login manually and place a bet vs do it via an application?

Also, I've managed to get this far anyway with Webbrowser, making it wait for textbox text is the last step :<

Comment: You really should read their terms of use. A lot of sites object to using an application

Comment: I would just read the terms of service. Automated tools are banned on some betting sites that I have seen.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is using a control designed for UI apps on a web server. I think you are going to need to use message loops to be able to let the browser "do stuff" and then come back to you before you return your ASP.NET request to your desktop browser.

Essentially the technique is to create a new control class based on `System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext` and then set the `ApartmentState` to STA on creation of that control. In itself it then contains the logic to create the `WebBrowser` control. You then have:

- the main thread which executes the ASP stuff (`Page_Load` etc.)

  - This then uses something like `AutoResetEvent` for signalling between threads
  - it passes that AutoResetEvent to the derived control that you create
  - it waits on that to prevent it returning your request before everything else is done
- A second thread, in which the `WebBrowser` lives
- And a third thread for the message loop, executing the `WebBrowser` event handles like the `Navigating` event handler and our callback functions. This is where you `Set` the AutoResetEvent to let the main thread return a response to the original caller.

The message loop can then be created by using `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext ctx)`, which avoids the need for a Windows Form itself in order to kick of the webbrowser.

This is really complex, but someone already did it: [CodePlex: Using the WebBrowser Control in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50544/Using-the-WebBrowser-Control-in-ASP-NET)

#### Thread.Sleep

*We now know this doesn't work for you*

Try using [`Thread.Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep.aspx):

```cs
stakeTextboxElement.InnerText = "3";
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
webbrowser.Navigate("javascript: placeBet();"); //they use javascript
```

#### Timer with/without a reset event

*This will probably have the same issues as Thread.Sleep*

If that doesn't work, then schedule your `Navigate` call using a [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) for a few seconds later.

```cs
function void DoNavigate(Object stateInfo) {
  AutoResetEvent arev = (AutoResetEvent)stateInfo; // *
  webbrowser.Navigate("javascript: placeBet();"); //they use javascript
  arev.Set(); // *
}

...
stakeTextboxElement.InnerText = "3";
// depending on your scenario you may need to wait for the navigate to happen, so use 
// a reset event for this
AutoResetEvent arev = new AutoResetEvent(false); // *
TimerCallback tcb = DoNavigate;
Timer stateTimer = new Timer(tcb, arev, 3000, Timeout.Infinite);
arev.WaitOne(); // *
```

#### Application.DoEvents

This isn't really available in ASP.NET, but if you are using windows forms (I'm not clear from your question if you are using Win Forms or ASP.NET) and the application is freezing the UI then you may need to let it do events using `Application.DoEvents`.

Comment: Hi there, 

    `var stakeTextboxElement = doc.GetElementById("stake");

                        stakeTextboxElement.Focus();

                        stakeTextboxElement.InnerText = txtBetAmmount.Text; 
                        Thread.Sleep(3000); //<-- Form is frozen and textbox is still empty at this stage
    webBrowser1.Navigate("javascript: placeBet();");`

I've also tried:
`stakeTextboxElement.SetAttribute("value", txtBetAmmount.Text);`
`SendKeys.Send(txtBetAmmount.Text);`
Both of them textbox is still empty by the time it sleeps.

Comment: The only way I've gotten it to work so far is:
`SendKeys.Send(txtBetAmmount.Text);
Application.DoEvents();
webBrowser1.Navigate("javascript: placeBet();");`

I only tried this as its easier to debug problems in WinForms for now, I want to use this in ASP.NET in the end.

Comment: @AlanCiantar. How about the timer method I've added? If the form is freezing then don't use the lines with `// *`. If you are using win forms you will need `DoEvents`, I'm not clear if you are using win forms or asp.net.

Comment: @AndyBrown: IMHO sleeping or delaying with a timer and waiting have the same effects: they **freeze the current thread**. And this is precisely this thread which is responsible for making the web-browser processing move forward. So continuing the events processing with **Application.DoEvents** seems the only viable solution.

Comment: Haha, sorry for being so confusing. In the end I want to be able to do this all in the background (WebBrowser is never shown) - everything automated on a website. At the moment I've created 2 projects - one asp.net webforms and a normal windows forms application. I'm using the windows forms to actually see the webbrowser work for now (debug/testing purposes).

Comment: @AlanCiantar. I now understand. So you need message loops. Its complex, very. I have added to my answer for you, and popped a reference in there with sample code. That should work for you.

Comment: @pragmateek. Then it sounds like message loops are the only way to go.

Comment: Yes precisely, otherwise it's like your boss saying: "Hey! Stop working right now!" and he comes back 1 hour later and complains "Have you finished? No? But WTF have you done during this entire hour?" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
stakeTextboxElement.InnerText = "3";

DateTime dueTime = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
while (DateTime.Now < dueTime)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
}

webbrowser.navigate("javascript: placeBet();");
```

Moreover you should not use *InnerText* which is not used by scripts to get the value of an input but rather update the ***Value*** property of the element.

```
stakeTextboxElement.Value = "3";
```

Comment: This actually fills the textbox correctly, but its still telling me that bet is too low. (Its definitely not) I'll continue looking into this in a bit later.

Comment: Ok I think I see the issue: don't use *InnerText* but the ***Value*** property of the element.

Comment: I assume you mean this `stakeTextboxElement.SetAttribute("value", txtBetAmmount.Text);` as stakeTextboxElement does not have a .Value - still doesnt work :)

Comment: Yes this is what I mean. What is the exact type of the input element in the HTML page?

Comment: I just looked at the input again, and i JUST realize it has keyup/down events (doh!). `<input type="text" id="stake" value="" class="BetClass" onkeyup="onStakeChange(this,event);" onkeypress="return onValidateFormat(this,event)">` which is probably why its never working using InnerText/SetAttribute. Now i need a way to simulate a key press...

Comment: Thank you by the way, you've been most helpful (as well as Andy Brown etc) <3 would upvote if i could :)

Comment: So you could maybe use a finer approach: once you've set the value you call: `stakeTextboxElement.RaiseEvent("onkeypress")`. It's worth a try...